# What's the difference between Maximum working current and upper limit of instantaneous current?

Tags: current, dc-motor, current-limiting

I am seeking to protect a [Mabuchi RS-380-SH4535 motor](https://product.mabuchi-motor.com/detail.html?id=100) + battery system using a BMS.   The battery is a single cell 18650 LiIon.

The motor has a stall current of 15 A at maximum battery voltage.
My battery has a maximum discharging current of 20 A.
What design parameters are appropiate to protect the battery and motor in normal operation?

I previously identified 3 potential sets of BMS specifications. I now realise that these are unsuited to my application (due to wrong intended battery chemistry) so rather than asking for a specific BMS

Question:

I'd like to know what technical aspects matter and why when designing or selecting a BMS and/or overcurrent protection system.

What's the relationship between stall current, maximum working current and maximum instantaneous current?

**______________**

Motor specification.
Stall current shown is at 6V.

[image]

**____________________________________**

NOW  REDUNDANT:

```
I have found 3 different BMS options:

1. Max. working current: 12 A. Upper limit of instantaneous current: 17 A.

2. Max. working current: 16 A. Upper limit of instantaneous current: 34 A.

3. Max. working current: 24 A. Upper limit of instantaneous current: 42 A.

   Which option should I choose and why?
```

Comment: Please provide a link to the datasheets.  "Max working current" would appear to be the maximum continuous current that is supported, subject to derating, etc.  "Upper limit of instantaneous current" could be the trip level for an overcurrent protection circuit or the absolute maximum rating of a component in the high current path, but without the datasheet we can't give a definitive answer.

Comment: I can't find the datasheets of the BMS but here the names:

1) HXYP-1S-4012A

2)I can't find it. But it starts also with "HXYP-1S"

3) HXYP-1S-5025

Here the aliexpress link: https://a.aliexpress.com/_mKg8Usw

As I see it's for a Lithium iron phosphate batteries and I am gonna use li ion batteries. But anyway we are only pretending that I use the right batteries what would be the adequate BMS of these three? 

DC motor which gonna be powered with a 3.7V 18650 battery: https://product.mabuchi-motor.com/detail.html?id=100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A datasheet, name, brand and related links will always be useful and help people provide a better answer.

But, the terms seem clear enough.

**Maximum working current** is the long term current that the system can tolerate.

**Upper limit of instantaneous current** is the current which will not cause damage to the BMS if maintained for a "short" period. The value of 'short' is uncertain and may or may not be in the datasheet.
Factors include:

- Thermal overload - noting that thermal dissipation rises approximately with current squared - so
  17:12A = 289:144 ~= 2:1 thermally.
  34:16A = 4.4:1 thermally
  42:24A = 3:1 thermally
- Instantaneous fusing current. Often wire fuses have ~ 2:1 fusing:operating current ratio but this varies very wisely with fuse type and design.

Choosing the BMS with 12A / 17 A working / maximum will be acceptable if the 15A stall current occurs only briefly and operating current is usually at or below 12A.

Choosing the BMS with 16A / 34A working / maximum allows longer stall periods but if a fault occurs that draws a fault current in the 20-34A range the BMS will not protect the battery.

The 34 / 42 A BMS is unsuitable as both the operating and maximum current levels are well above operating or significant battery damage levels.

Comment: I can't find the datasheets of the BMS but here the names:

1) HXYP-1S-4012A

2)I can't find it. But it starts also with "HXYP-1S"

3) HXYP-1S-5025

Here the aliexpress link: https://a.aliexpress.com/_mKg8Usw

As I see it's for a Lithium iron phosphate batteries and I am gonna use li ion batteries. But anyway we are only pretending that I use the right batteries what would be the adequate BMS of these three? 

DC motor which gonna be powered with a 3.7V 18650 battery: https://product.mabuchi-motor.com/detail.html?id=100

Comment: A LiFePO4 BMS is completely unsuitable for LiIon cells.  || [The motor that you linked to](https://product.mabuchi-motor.com/detail.html?id=100) shows a 24A stall current. It will probably be lower with a LiIon cell - about 4V max --> about 16A which is about what you said :-). ||

Comment: ...  The BMS aims to protect the battery from undervoltage, overvoltage and overcurrent. In this case if the battery is rated at a max current drain > stall current then the overcurrent portion of the BMS will be used only for faults and is less important. The BMS MUST tolerate stall current if you do not wish it to "intervene" under stall OR can be set much lower IF you wish to limit motor current to closer to operating BUT that's properly a circuit and not a BMS function.